# convert Unicode to normal string

Tags: python, regex, unicode, unicode-string

I use this function to replace specific unicode characters

```
def removeTashkeel(original_text):
cleanText = re.sub(u'[\u064B-\u0652\u06D4\u0670\u0674\u06D5\u0695-\u06ED]+', '',original_text.decode("utf-8"))    
return cleanText
```

I pass this text as an argument 
"\nعذرا ڕ .بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِي.عشان هو  ڕ http://www.google.com عمـــــر واحد# و@ الوقت\" \n اللي هنضيعه هنتحاسب عليه،:p:p:ppp انا مش هكمل الرواية دي :D it was really 3  4 awesome"

when I return the cleanText this is what i get 

u'\n\u0639\u0630\u0631\u0627  .\u0628\u0633\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u062d\u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u062d\u064a.\u0639\u0634\u0627\u0646 \u0647\u0648   http://www.google.com \u0639\u0645\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0631 \u0648\u0627\u062d\u062f# \u0648@ \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0642\u062a" \n \u0627\u0644\u0644\u064a \u0647\u0646\u0636\u064a\u0639\u0647 \u0647\u0646\u062a\u062d\u0627\u0633\u0628 \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0647\u060c:p:p:ppp \u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0634 \u0647\u0643\u0645\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0648\u0627\u064a\u0629 \u062f\u064a :D it was really 3  4 awesome' 

when i replace the line 
`return cleanText`
 with the line 
`print cleanText`
I get the result 
 br>

عذرا ڕ .بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِي.عشان هو  ڕ: عمـــــر واحد و الوقت 
 اللي هنضيعه هنتحاسب عليه،:p:p:ppp انا مش هكمل الرواية دي :D 3  4

how can i return the same result produced by print using return because I am not able to use the returned value as a normal string anymore even when i do `cleanText.encode('utf-8')

I would be very thankful for any of your help`

Comment: You have the correct value **already**. You are looking at the `repr()` representation of a Unicode string, which is formatted for debugging purposes and uses `\uhhhh` hex escapes to make the string ASCII-safe. You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Use Python 3 to see the correct text in `repr` as well.

Comment: i read that other answer but still I don't know how to get the value that is printed inside anew string, can you please explain it furthur for me ?

Comment: i used python 3 and i did return repr(cleanText) but still i get the unicode representation not the actual string

Comment: Now i understand you , I tried o continue working on it as normal and saving the value and the value is being proccessed as a normal string , thanks for your help